# Docker-Compose error in powershell only: "Couldn't connect to docker daemon...."

Tags: powershell, docker

I am getting below error in powershell while executing docker-compose command:
[image]

While same command is working fine from Docker Quickstart Terminal:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have set the right environment variables in your Powershell session first.

See [`docker-machine env`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/):

```
$ docker-machine.exe env --shell powershell dev
$Env:DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = "1"
$Env:DOCKER_HOST = "tcp://192.168.99.101:2376"
$Env:DOCKER_CERT_PATH = "C:\Users\captain\.docker\machine\machines\dev"
$Env:DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME = "dev"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# docker-machine.exe env --shell=powershell dev | Invoke-Expression
```

Replace '`dev`' by the name of your machine.

Comment: I am aware of it but was blocked by stackoverflow to accept it sooner :). done it now

Comment: @GauravGupta no problem. Thank you

Comment: One more thing, this command is session specific. Is it possible to somehow make it permanent?

Comment: @GauravGupta Sure, put those command in a bashrc-like for your powershell: see http://superuser.com/a/1045659/141. This powershell  profiles are scripts which are executed when you start a shell.